# MYSQL - ORDER BY conditional two fields

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I need order mysql results in datatables.
I actually have this

```
PRODUCT   STAGE  
  35        1
  36        1
  37        1 
  35        2
  36        2
  37        2
```

And i need this

```
PRODUCT   STAGE  
  35        1
  35        2
  36        1 
  36        2
  37        1
  37        2
```

Actually have not an ORDER or GROUP BY in mysql statement.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order by product and stage

```
select product, stage 
from my_table 
order by product, stage
```

in the way for the same product the rows are ordered  by stage

Comment: i still the same results, this it's my mysql
    SELECT 
 pedidos.id,
 pedidos.correlativo,
 pedidos.tipo_trat,
 pedidos.nombres,
 pedidos.apellidos,
 pedidos.estado,
 etapas.etapa,
 etapas.estado_etapa,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM etapas WHERE token = pedidos.token) 
 AS num_etapas
 
 FROM 
 pedidos
 
 INNER JOIN etapas ON (etapas.token = pedidos.token)
 
 WHERE tipo_trat = 2 and pedidos.cliente = $id and pedidos.token = 
     pedidos.token order by correlativo, etapa

Comment: Sorry, wrong culumn order un datatables. i just order and works. thanks a lot @scaisEdge